# raspi-config on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, raspi-config

i wanted to enable SPI on my raspberry pi 3 but in ubuntu mate it says the command "raspi-config" is not found, what is the alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspi-config is now installed on Ubuntu Mate by default. You can call it just the same as on Raspbian, and it works the same.

[image]

I know this is an old thread, but this may still be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install raspi-config
```

did it for me. It was not availlable by default on my Mate-version on Raspi2. 
Now I can start raspi-config in order to enable SPI. 
TNX @Mohanad Kaleia, @Jacobm001, @hat and OP @Ralph

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually edit `config.txt` to enable the Device Tree overlay. `raspi-config` is just a front end to the various configuration files.

AFAIK the SPI  entry is there, but commented out (mine have been modified so many times I don't know the default).

Read the `README` in `overlays` for more detail.

Comment: Where is supposed to be this `config.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

This is the steps for ubuntu 18.04, maybe it will help you:

```
sudo echo "deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7FA3303E
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install raspi-config
```

Comment: Why to use unsupported **jessie**? Doesn't it work from **buster**?

Answer (score 0):

You can install it on Ubuntu Mate:

```
sudo apt-get install raspi-config
```