# Setting up Static IP on Pi3

Tags: pi-3, static-ip

I have a question about setting up my Pi with a static IP address so I can access it remotely.  Currently I attempting to use [this guide](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update) to set up my Pi with a static IP.

This is the text I added to the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.29/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

When I save `etc/dhcpcd.conf` with this text and reboot, if i put `ifconfig` in the terminal, there is no eth0 interface.  This is a screenshot of what I get when I run `ifconfig` in the terminal:

[image: terminal output]

As you can see, instead of `eth0` I have `enxb827eb819487`.  I have no idea what this is, but it is obviously the interface name for my wired connection.  The question is, why?

Comment: Possible duplication with [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/raspberry-pi-3-eth0-wrongfully-named-enx](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/raspberry-pi-3-eth0-wrongfully-named-enx)

Comment: [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor remark first: Raspberry Pi 3 its just the hardware, the question is regarding the OS (Operating System) example "Raspbian" and what date the image file have, there are differences in different OS versions.

**1. Regarding Fixed IP.**

This is defined in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
auto enxb827eb819487
iface enxb827eb819487 inet static
    address 192.0.2.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.0.2.254
```

See ref. below.

**2. Network interface names.**

Quote: **Predictable Network Interface Names**

*As if Stretch, the old network names like eth0, eth1 have gone away as the device name can change. The new names are similar to these: enp6s0, enp8s0, enp0s31f6, enp5s0.*

Ref.: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration